# AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to my class

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have problem with my android java code, I hope you can help me with this.

I have my class with ImageView parent... some like this:

```
public abstract class BaseStatus extends ImageView
{
    public BaseStatus(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
}

public class BluetoothStatus extends BaseStatus
{
    public BluetoothStatus(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
}
```

and I want to get the component as ImageView from the XML, you know...

```
BluetoothStatus btStatus;
btStatus = (BluetoothStatus) findViewById(R.id.bt_status); // ERROR
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt_status"
        android:src="@drawable/bluetooth"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lb_laser" />
```

and i got this message:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to net.antiradary.radarhunter.activity.status.BluetoothStatus

Why i can not cast ImageView into BluetoothStatus? 
Thank you for you answers!

Comment: AppCompatImageView implement TintableBackgroundView and extends ImageView. Now you are trying to cast parent into child which breach the inheritance property of OOPs

Comment: Thanks guys, but public abstract class BaseStatus extends AppCompatImageView got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was enough to do jus this...

```
<net.antiradary.radarhunter.activity.status.BluetoothStatus
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_bluetooth"
        android:src="@drawable/bluetooth"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lb_laser" />
```

and in my class make constructor like this

```
class BluetoothStatus extends ImageView
{
    public BluetoothStatus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: You better extend `AppCompatImageView`

Answer (score -1):

I know i am late to the party, but just in case some is banging his head for same problem, here is one possible solution that worked for me when i was trying to add zoom functionality in my pager adapter images.

**Info:** this is not the exact answer, but a possible solution for those who are facing the same problem. I am posting this because i didn't fount this solution approach anywhere in stackOverflow

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/head_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/head_image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the above code, just Replace `<ImageView` with `<com.yourPackage.TouchImageView`.

**TouchImageView**  (or any other class) is a custom class (you need to make)which should extend **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView**